# Facebook Graph API - does not return all values for page_fans_country?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to built an small Facebook analytics solution that allows the benchmarking and analysis of Facebook pages by fancount/likes.

Unfortunately some bigger pages are setup as global pages, e.g.: 
https://www.facebook.com/CocaCola

In this case the Likes show the aggregate sum across all countries (106,831,744)

I would like to know the number of likes by market/region (e.g. US, Germany)
Based on tips across the web and from this forum I have used the following query for page_fans_country:

https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/insights/page_fans_country?access_token=[my access token]
(as a variation also this: /cocacola/insights?metric=page_fans_country)

However this returns a list that does not seem complete:

- It only features 45 markets (also the maximum when I run the query for other brands)
- It does not contain bigger markets such as US or Germany (DE)
- The numbers don't add up to the likes shown on the page (5.874.635 vs.
  106.831.744)

Even the professional analytics tool Socialbakers returns the same "smaller" number. https://www.socialbakers.com/statistics/facebook/pages/detail/40796308305-coca-cola

Am i looking at the wrong metric here?

Or has Facebook restricted access to the (full) page_fans_country breakdown if you don't have page insights access?
Thanks.

Comment: Since API v2.11, _all_ metrics now require a page access token for the page in question, according to documentation. Plus, what it says for `page_storytellers_by_country` regarding the countries probably applies to `page_fans_country` as well.

Comment: The api limits the results to the top 45 countries. According to [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/insights): "The number of people, aggregated per country, that like your Page. Only the 45 countries with the most people that like your Page are included."